# Rename files using regular expression in linux

Tags: regex, terminal, rename

I have a set of files named like

```
20151016_174721.jpg
```

and I want to rename them like

```
2015-10-16 17.47.21.jpg
```

I tried using `rename` using the following:

```
rename -n "s/(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})_(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2}).*$/$1-$2-$3 $4.$5.$6.jpg/" *.jpg
```

But it ends up telling me

```
20151016_174721.jpg renamed as -- ...jpg
```

And I cannot understand why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
rename 's/(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})_(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})(.*)$/$1-$2-$3 $4.$5.$6$7/' *.jpg
```

Make sure to use single quotes in your pattern to avoid shell attempting to expand `$1`, `$2` etc.